# php generate random number rn=0.41441782722922393

Tags: php

I want to generate new random number like **0.4144178272292239** for sending the number along with request to server. But I do not how to generate this number by php to send the number with the request like "include/classes/modules/search.inc.php?rn=0.41441782722922393".

So could you please advice me too?

Comment: Googling "PhP random number" would have been a lot quicker than writing a SO post.

Answer (score 0):

```
$num = rand();
$num = $num / 10 ** strlen($num);
echo $num;
```

Outputs:

```
0.220578263
```